# How to parse information on website section for registered users only using php

Tags: php, parsing, header

I'v tried to change my headers using header() function both like curl_setopt() but my headers did not change. Is there any addition actions need to change my headers? If the section of website which I want to parse is only for registered users, they can keep cookies with auth-data. Do I need additional header information got from auth-cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the cookie-information with each request. This could be done easly with curl.

http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/php-curl-cookies-example/

Comment: I'v did it in such way <?  $ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
$ch = curl_init ("http://main-page.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

$ch = curl_init ("http://admin.main-page.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch); ?> BUT NOTHING CHANGED

Comment: I've found solution : $ch = curl_init();  
   
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "auth_cookie=auth_code;other_cokie_name=other_cookie_content");